# Error when calling file:lines() in for loop

Tags: for-loop, io, lua

I have got the following code:

```
function getusers(file)
    print (type(file))
    for line in file:lines() do
    user, value = string.match(file,"(UserName=)(.-)\n")
    print(value)
    end

    f:close()
    end

 f = assert(io.open('file2.ini', "r"))
 t = f:read("*all")
 getusers(t)
```

The return of:

```
print(type(file))
```

is type string. Lua returns me the error code:

> lua: reader.lua:3: attempt to call method 'lines' (a nil value)

I don't know how to fix this problem. If I just use the lines between the for and the end (the lines in the for loop) it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is a file handler, while `t` is a string that contains the content. You are trying to call `io.lines`, so it should be a file handler. In fact, you don't need `t` at all.

```
function getusers(file)
    print(type(file))
    for line in file:lines() do
        user, value = string.match(line,"(UserName=)(.*)")
        print(value)
    end

    f:close()
end

f = assert(io.open('t.txt', "r"))
getusers(f)
```

I've also modified the pattern to `(UserName=)(.*)` because now you are matching each line, not the whole file.

Comment: The code just returns 'nil' for every line in the 'input file' I gave. Seems like the filtering for UserName doesn't work now anymore.

Comment: @user3714446 See the edit. Either pass in `t` and process the whole content, or pass in `f` and use `io.lines` to process each line. Your call.

Comment: I edited code in the first post. It doesn't work any more. I just need to get the values behind 'UserName='.

Comment: @user3714446 I've edited again, it's basically the first version I posted. Your previous pattern doesn't work to match each line now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the smartest way, but now I use:

```
function getusers(file)
for line in file:lines() do
    user, value = string.match(line,"(UserName=)(.*)")
    if value ~= nil then
        print(value)
    end 
end

f:close()
end

f = assert(io.open('file2.ini', "r"))
getusers(f)
```

As you may see, I check the value of 'value' before printing it.

Comment: Yes, that check is correct. However, it's best to keep each of your question [complete by itself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because few people would read your previous question to find out what problem you are trying to solve. I happen to answer your previous question, so I know the background, but nobody else does. I rolled back your question for the same reason.